# How ignore/hide/deactivate my policy non-compliance state and get 100% compliance?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Below is my policy definition and is **correctly working** (policy is responsible to assign tags from resource group to resources):

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "inheritTags",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "metadata": {
      "createdBy": "3332dc03-2402-46e3-9098-c7350b0bc8dd",
      "createdOn": "2019-11-25T14:49:57.8136557Z",
      "updatedBy": "3332dc03-2402-46e3-9098-c7350b0bc8dd",
      "updatedOn": "2019-11-26T19:43:48.752452Z"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "value": "[resourceGroup().tags]",
            "exists": "true"
          },
          {
            "value": "[resourceGroup().tags]",
            "notEquals": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "modify",
        "details": {
          "operations": [
            {
              "operation": "addOrReplace",
              "field": "tags",
              "value": "[resourceGroup().tags]"
            }
          ],
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/78afced4-1c58-4e66-8242-c042890d34c3/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/9f2a0e94-5ada-47b0-8125-42464f93cf37",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "9f2a0e94-5ada-47b0-8125-42464f93cf37"
}
```

Nevertheless in **Overview** tab on **Policy** page I have information that assigned policy definition is in **Non-compliant** state:

[image]

Reason for that? **Different** values due to comparing previous state to expected state and I know that source of "issues" are keywords like `exists`, `notEquals` and so on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/determine-non-compliance#compliance-reasons

[image]

How to **ignore those compliance messages** and get resource compliance, you know tags are **correctly** assigned so what is the problem? or maybe I have wrong understanding of azure policies?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The resources that are coming up as non-compliant is because they do not have the same tags as  the RG. For some resources, modify won't because they don't support tags or don't support updating/adding tags. I can't tell what type of resource it is so I can't say forsure that is the issues. If this is the case that those resources don't support tags, then you can just excluded that resource from the assignment to see the compliance percentage not including those. (Edit the assignment and add an exclusion)

Comment: Sure I can exclude some resources in assignment tab via eg. "resource group" but I want to do this more dynamically by policy, is it possible? and if yes, then how to exclude those specific resources? Another thing is that I have non-complaint state for resources that have exactly **same tags** like RG so what I can do here? (I added a screenshot)

Comment: A more dynamic way of excluding a specific resource would be to include that in the if statement of the Policy definition. (If not resource type x & has these tags then modify). Also, in the built in (Inherit a tag from the resource group if missing), it first establishes if a tag is present in the resource, however you check if the resource group has tags not if the resource has tags. I would suggest implementing the builtin to see if you get the desired results from that